# Fixed position p is more pixels from bottom than specified

Tags: css, css-position

This p is within a nav that is also fixed position, but that doesn't matter, right? I tried using fixed position as the only way it seemed I could place the text tucked into the curve of the nav (which has a big border-radius on the top right that is partly off-screen, creating a tab feel). It does take the element out of the flow, but doesn't place it where one would expect. It's located [here.](http://moonwards.com/)

```
#directory {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -95px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    z-index: 20;
}
#directory p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 21;
}
```

Comment: The `p` tag has a default margin on it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara From the browser? Add * { padding: 0; margin: 0;} ?

Comment: Yes, from the browser. A reset like that would work, or you could add `margin: 0` to you `#directory p` selector.

Comment: Also, as far as I am aware, using `position:fixed` on a child of an element that is already fixed will actually act like `position:absolute`.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I suppose i could do something that would make it scroll if it was positioned absolutely, and check? I'll fill in some dummy content.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, it stays in place, and i guess the point is moot in this context - it's parent is fixed, what could possibly push it out of position?

Comment: If you remove the position values it snaps into place.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#directory p` to `position:relative;`

I added a screenshot to show that changing the position to relative does in fact work.

[image]

Comment: The parent is mostly off screen - I wasn't sure about doing that. (The downvote isn't mine though.)